# Download procedure not working for some files Apex

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-apex

I've been having a problem with an APEX procedure used to download files (code taken straight from the Oracle webpage):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE download_my_file(p_file in number) AS
        v_mime  VARCHAR2(48);
        v_length  NUMBER;
        v_file_name VARCHAR2(2000);
        Lob_loc  BLOB;
BEGIN
        SELECT MIME_TYPE, BLOB_CONTENT, name,DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(blob_content)
                INTO v_mime,lob_loc,v_file_name,v_length
                FROM oehr_file_subject
                WHERE id = p_file;
              --
              -- set up HTTP header
              --
                    -- use an NVL around the mime type and 
                    -- if it is a null set it to application/octect
                    -- application/octect may launch a download window from windows
                    owa_util.mime_header( nvl(v_mime,'application/octet'), FALSE );

                -- set the size so the browser knows how much to download
                htp.p('Content-length: ' || v_length);
                -- the filename will be used by the browser if the users does a save as
                htp.p('Content-Disposition:  attachment; filename="'||replace(replace(substr(v_file_name,instr(v_file_name,'/')+1),chr(10),null),chr(13),null)|| '"');
                -- close the headers            
                owa_util.http_header_close;
                -- download the BLOB
                wpg_docload.download_file( Lob_loc );
end download_my_file;
/
```

The procedure works for pdf files and images, but not with excel or word files, giving me an "ORACLE 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR".
   Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a server log file that gives more details of what went wrong?

Comment: not working for SOME files or ANY files?

Comment: Maybe there's something funny going on in your generated filename field. What happens if you change it to use a static filename for all files?

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys! 
@Typo , if the file has the pdf extension, it always works. I tried uploading images too, and it also works. The problem is with 'docx' or 'xls' files.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp , as soon as I get to work, I'll give it a try

Comment: Turns out @JeffreyKemp was right...It was a problem with the filename (the previous developer of the system made it as a user input in the form). As soon as I made some corrections on the database and changed the way the filename was being read, it worked.
Thanks!

Comment: For future reference you might want to add an exception handler to this routine that logs any errors (e.g. use apex_debug.message). 500 Internal Server Error is commonly seen on the client when an oracle procedure raises an exception.